# Contact form and boolean variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formContact');
const nameContact = document.getElementById('name');
const emailContact = document.getElementById('email');
const messageContact = document.getElementById('message');
const headerContact = document.querySelector('.headerContact')
const thankYou = document.querySelector('.Thankyou');

const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};


let isValid = true;

function checkInputs(){

  //get the values from the inputs or textarea

  const nameValue = nameContact.value.trim();
  const emailValue = emailContact.value.trim();
  const messageValue = messageContact.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(nameContact, 'Name cannot be blank');
  } else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(nameContact);
  }

  if (emailValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if(!isValidEmail(emailValue)){
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Please add a valid email adress');
  } else{
    setSuccesFor(emailContact);
  }

  if (messageValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message cannot be blank');
  } else if (messageValue.length < 20){
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message need to be at least 20 characters');
  }
  else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(messageContact);
  }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
  isValid=false;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');

  //add error message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccesFor(input){
  isValid=true;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');
  //remove message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText='';

  //add success class
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';

}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){
    form.remove();
    headerContact.classList.add('hide');
    thankYou.classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#merci').innerHTML = `<h3>Dear ${nameThk}, thank you for reaching out ! </h3>`;
    
  }

});

let nameThk = "";
nameContact.addEventListener('input', (e) =>{
  nameThk = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
.containerContact {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
}

.containerContact h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
  resize: none;
}

.form-control textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control #textareaChecks {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control.success input {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.form-control.success textarea {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error textarea {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

#Error {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ContactSubmit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  outline: none;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.containerThank {
  height: 300px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

.containerThank h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.containerThank p {
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
      align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2dc9b6eb01.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Statsmap.ch</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
    <section class="Contact">
        <div class="containerContact">
          <div class="headerContact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
          </div>
          <form action=""  class="formContact" id="formContact" novalidate>
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text"  id="name" placeholder="First and Last name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="email"  name = "email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <textarea id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <span id="Error"></span>                
              </div>
              <button id="ContactSubmit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <div class="Thankyou hide">
            <div class="containerThank">
            <h3 id="merci"></h3>
            <p>Our team is going to get back to you as soon as possible</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
 
  
  <script src="JS/contact.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/newsletter.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/scroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on a contact form and I want it to disappear after different validations. Everything works fine but I'm a bit of a perfectionist. I use a boolean variable ('IsValid') to delete the contact form and add a message.

The only thing I don't understand is the fact that if my textarea is filled, the other boxes don't need to be validated to delete the form.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
const form = document.getElementById('formContact');
const nameContact = document.getElementById('name');
const emailContact = document.getElementById('email');
const messageContact = document.getElementById('message');
const headerContact = document.querySelector('.headerContact')
const thankYou = document.querySelector('.Thankyou');

const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};


let isValid = false;

function checkInputs(){

  //get the values from the inputs or textarea

  const nameValue = nameContact.value.trim();
  const emailValue = emailContact.value.trim();
  const messageValue = messageContact.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(nameContact, 'Name cannot be blank');
  } else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(nameContact);
  }

  if (emailValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if(!isValidEmail(emailValue)){
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Please add a valid email adress');
  } else{
    setSuccesFor(emailContact);
  }

  if (messageValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message cannot be blank');
  } else if (messageValue.length < 20){
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message need to be at least 20 characters');
  }
  else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(messageContact);
  }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
  isValid=false;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');

  //add error message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccesFor(input){
  isValid=true;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');
  //remove message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText='';

  //add success class
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';

}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){
    form.remove();
    headerContact.classList.add('hide');
    thankYou.classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#merci').innerHTML = `<h3>Dear ${nameThk}, thank you for reaching out ! </h3>`;
    
  }

});

let nameThk = "";
nameContact.addEventListener('input', (e) =>{
  nameThk = e.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of your validation checks call `setSuccesFor()` if that validation succeeds. This overrides all the previous validations.

You should initialize `isValid` to `true`. Failing validations can set it to `false`, but they shouldn't set it back to `true`. So remove `isValid = true` from `setSuccesFor()` -- they should just set the style of the input, not reset this variable.

Comment: By doing what you said, it does not remove the form to display a message.

Comment: Can you change the code in your question into an executable snippet with the HTML? Then I'll show how to modify it in my answer.

Comment: i've just upload my question to a snippet. Thanks for helping

Comment: You didn't remove `isValid = true` from `setSuccessFor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setSuccessFor` function sets `isValid` to true.

`messageValue` is the last item validated, so if it passes, isValid will be true and your submit listener removes the form, regardless of the status of the other inputs.

```js
let isValid = false;

function setSuccesFor(input){
  isValid=true; // <== sets the whole thing to valid
  // ...other stuff...
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){ // <== a single input will set this to true
    form.remove();
    // ...
```

I'd recommend you check out the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript).

Comment: I understand the logic of what you said, but in fact, when I simply enter a name or email address, the submit listener does not delete the form. That's why I'm a little confused

Comment: Ah. Right. See my updated answer.